# creating new table error

Tags: sql-server, database

I created this table and I am trying to populate it but I keep getting an errror.

Here is the create table statement:

```
--Creating the table
CREATE TABLE tblModule07Partition_RI
(
    column01 int,
    column02 varchar not null CONSTRAINT column02default DEFAULT 'N/A',
CONSTRAINT column01Key PRIMARY KEY (column01)
)
ON psPartitionModule07_RI (column01)
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW)
GO

--6 Inserting records into the table

INSERT INTO tblModule07Partition_RI
VALUES (50,'First Partition 1')
```

The error is this:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'tblModule07Partition_RI'.
```

Any advice?

Comment: Try prefixing your tablename with `dbo` (`dbo.tblMod...`). You can also check the system tables to see what object was created.

Comment: **WHICH version** of SQL Server are you using? And where exactly are you getting the error - on the `CREATE TABLE`, or on the `INSERT`??

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE tblModule07Partition_RI (
    column01 int,
    column02 varchar not null DEFAULT 'N/A',
    CONSTRAINT column01Key PRIMARY KEY (column01)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Create Table script def works in SQL Server 2000, if I remove the

```
ON psPartitionModule07_RI (column01)
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW)
```

section.

Naturally this wouldn't work on my server but it shows that the rest of the code *does* create a table. So perhaps you need to check that this part is correct.

That said, your `column02` definition doesn't fit with your data, because you haven't defined the length of the column correctly.

If you want to enter **'First Partition 1'** then you need to define it as (at least) `varchar(17)`

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what was happening. I did not defined column 2 correctly giving me the error.